# Finding length of shortest path between two vertices with igraph in r?

Tags: r, igraph

This is my first time using igraph with r (also my first stack overflow question) and I'm trying to find a shortest path on a graph. I know how to use `get_shortest_path` to find the list of vertices that the shortest path would go through and that seems to work fine. My issue is that I cannot figure out easily how to find the distance. I know about the `distance` function but it seems to not find the distance on a directed graph. Here's an example on a simple graph

```
v1 = c("a","b")
v2 = c("ar","br")
weight = c(10,10)

test_df = data.frame(v1, v2, weight)
g <- test_df %>% graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE)
```

Running `distances(g, "a", to="ar")` returns 10 as expected

However running `distances(g, "ar", to="a")` also returns 10 despite there being no directed edge from ar to a

I tried looking at other questions but no one seemed to talk about directed edges. Is there something here I'm just completely missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the mode= argument.  From the help file:

> ```
> mode: Character constant, gives whether the shortest paths to or
>       from the given vertices should be calculated for directed
>       graphs. If ‘out’ then the shortest paths _from_ the vertex,
>       if ‘in’ then _to_ it will be considered. If ‘all’, the
>       default, then the corresponding undirected graph will be
>       used, ie. not directed paths are searched. This argument is
>       ignored for undirected graphs.
> ```

Taking that into account we have:

```
distances(g, "ar", to = "a", mode = "out")
##      a
## ar Inf

distances(g, "a", to = "ar", mode = "out")
##   ar
## a 10
```